# Does Stackoverflow track what specific user is searching for..?

Tags: stackapps, support

Does Stackoverflow track what specific user is searching for..?

is that data available through APIs provided..?

Comment: Doubtful and No.

Comment: hmm.. I am thinking same..
But imagine if that data is also available then trends of search and trends of user switches.. technology relations.. most trending technology.. lots of analytical data can be populated.